# Getting Array inside Json in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am getting the Json object having array holding json objects.

```
{
    "wpDetails": [
        {
            "inputPath": null,
            "outputPath": null,
            "drive": null,
            "spaceRequired": "12"
        },
        {
            "inputPath": null,
            "outputPath": null,
            "drive": null,
            "spaceRequired": "12"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to access **inputPath** . Using Angular2. Below is my code but no luck.

```
this.
serverService.getWpDetails(this.selectedServer,this.selectedWpName)
.subscribe(
        (response:Response)=> {

          const responseJsonDetails=response.json().wpDetails;
          console.log("msg is:" + responseJsonDetails );
          for(const wpDetail of responseJsonDetails){
            console.log("inside for loop" + wpDetail);

          }

        },
        (error)=>console.log(error)

      );
```

I am getting [object object] on console. Can any one help me on this.

Comment: Why don't you just add wpDetail.inputPath ?

Comment: Finally got it after few more attempts. Used below line of code.

Comment: response.json().wpDetails[1].inputPath   it worked.

Comment: You mean inside the loop ? Weird. Did you try a JSON.stringify to check if what you get is what you expect ?

Comment: Here i used wpDetails[1] because wpDetails is array so i used '1'. Or we can loop and use wpDetails[i]. And i did not used JSON.stringify, i used Json() provided by Angular2( Because i want to traverse json object only)